# Zsh - The stdout with append (>>) doesn't create a new file, like bash does

Tags: zsh

In *bash* when I have an empty directory and type
`echo "bar" >> foo.txt`, it creates a file without problem, when I try the same on *zsh*, I receive an error of "file doesn't exist"

MacOS (Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0)

zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)

[zimfw](https://github.com/zimfw/zimfw) installed on iTerm2

Comment: Can you add more details? It works fine for me on zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says on the [zsh docummentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Redirection)

> (>> word)
> Open file word for writing in append mode as standard output. If the file does not exist, and the CLOBBER and APPEND_CREATE options are both unset, this causes an error; otherwise, the file is created.

My problem was the clobber and the append_create, so just adding to the *~/.zshrc* the `setopt clobber` and `setopt append_create` solved the case for MacOS, with [zimfw](https://github.com/zimfw/zimfw) installed

Comment: Actually you just need to setopt append_create.

Comment: One of them is sufficient, i.e. either `clobber` or `apend_create`. Actually, `append_create` is meant for those who **do** want `noclobber`, but also want to have `>>` create the file if necessary.

Comment: @user1934428, indeed, do you think the documentation is wrong?

Comment: In my zsh man page, this is documented in this way (zsh 5.8).